# Configure devise login page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin, resque

I use ActiveAdmin as back-office which login page is located at:

```
https://my-back-office.url/admin/login
```

I configured my resque web server to be located at:

```
https://my-back-office.url/admin/resque
```

To do so I configured my `routes.rb` file this way:

```
authenticate :admin_user do
    mount Resque::Server.new, at: '/admin/resque'
end

devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
```

My issue is that when a user tries to access a resque page without being authenticated, he is redirected to:

```
https://my-back-office.url/admin/resque/admin/login
```

My question is the following: How can I configure the resque web server to redirect to /admin/login when the authentication is invalid?

Comment: show me your web server's config. i think it redirects unauthenticated user to the originally requested URI

Comment: Which config do you need to see? the resque web server configuration?

Comment: Yes the configuration file

Comment: I'm not sure wether that is what you need, but I use the resque sinatra server embeded with the resque gem:
https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/1-x-stable/lib/resque/server.rb

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
**routes.rb**

```
mount Resque::Server.new, at: '/admin/resque'

devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
```